# How can I download to Excel?

Tags: excel, resources, coldfusion, download

I'd like to go about offering a "download to excel" functionality for several different sets of data available on different parts of my coldfusion website. I'm using coldfusion and would love to use freely available custom tags / libraries that can help me accomplish this instead of coding it all myself from scratch. I've been pointed to [cflib.org](http://www.cflib.org) but am not sure how to get started. Anyone have any ideas, comments, or resources about downloading coldfusion website data to excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, we used the [Query2Excel](http://www.cflib.org/index.cfm?event=page.udfbyid&udfid=560) function from cflib.org, and modified it slightly to suit our specific needs.

Answer (score 5):

An approach that I have used in the past for an intranet with a load of tabular statistical data is to take advantage of the fact that Excel can read HTML.

On pages that I intend to provide Excel links for, I write out the core table as HTML to a file and include a link to that file in the rendered page. You can then serve this page with an .xls extension, use meta headers or even use an intermediary page with CFCONTENT in order to have your browser fire up Excel to display the content.

This approach can be extended for an arbitrary number of tables per page. You would have to write a tag to contain the table which will then take care of writing the file and supplying the download link for all HTML content contained within.

Sorry for the lack of example code. If my description of the process has left you scratching your head then I'll provide some examples for you.

Comment: +1 - We use this too. Makes it nice and simple to have an option to output the report as Excel or just plain HTML. All you need to do it adjust the headers for Excel: add `<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel">` and `<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="filename=my-file-name.xls">`.

Comment: <scratch, scratch> Do you mind providing some example code? ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use an html table, as in:

```
<cfquery name="data" datasource="whatever">
...
</cfquery>

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=fileName.xls">
<cfcontent type="application/x-msexcel" reset="true">

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Col1</td>
            <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <cfoutput query="data">
            <tr>
                <td>#data.Col1#</td>
                <td>#data.Col2#</td>
            </tr>
        </cfoutput>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

hth,

larry

Comment: I think I'd use <th> tags instead of <td> tags in my <thead> section, but other than that, this is a good example of what @Steve Martin described above.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on ColdFusion 9, you can always use cfspreadsheet:

http://www.cfquickdocs.com/cf9/#cfspreadsheet

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WS434C35B0-279B-4051-A61B-D84B5D76189C.html

Comment: Still on Coldfusion 8... is this available or it's new to 9?

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Ciaran Archer's answer, I usually use CSV to accomplish this, which Excel will open up from the web if installed on a client's PC. Assuming the data you're working with is coming out of a database, use the [QueryToCSV](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1239-Updated-Converting-A-ColdFusion-Query-To-CSV-Using-QueryToCSV-.htm)() from Ben Nadel's site as such:

```
<cfquery name="data" datasource="">
...
</cfquery>
<cfinclude template="fun_queryToCSV.cfm">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="filename=my-file-name.xls">
<cfcontent type="test/csv" reset="true">
<cfoutput>#querytoCSV(data)#</cfoutput>
```

The "reset" on cfcontent clears the response buffer so that the only thing inside of it is what comes after. Alternately, if you already have the data as file, cfcontent has a "file" attribute that will serve its contents up directly.

Answer (score 0):

For those on Coldfusion 9+ and able to use cfspreadsheet, you can leverage SpreadsheetReadBinary() to make the spreadsheet downloadable without having to write the spreadsheet to a file first.

Comment: True, but [cfspreadsheet was already mentioned on another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4508522/104223). Rather than post the same answer twice, this should be comment.