# CF Save As Dialog box and setting Save Type As

Tags: coldfusion

I am using CF 10 and I am trying to create a save as dialog box appear and set the save as type as xls (Excel Extension) so that my report can be easily saved in excel. I was thinking I could maybe do this with

```
<cfelseif FORM.Format IS "xls">
    <cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel">
    <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=fileName.xls">
```

but that does not open up the correct dialog box. Does anyone know how this may be accomplished?

This is what should appear:[image]

```
    <cfelseif FORM.Format IS "xls">
    <cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel">
    <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=fileName.xls">


    <cfset result = {} />
<cftry>
    <cfset date1 = CREATEODBCDATETIME(form.StartDate & '00:00:00')>
    <cfset date2 = CREATEODBCDATETIME(form.EndDate & '23:59:59')>

    <cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#" name="GetLocationInfo">
        SELECT  *
        FROM    cl_checklists
        WHERE   date >=  <cfqueryparam value="#date1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" />
                AND date <= <cfqueryparam value="#date2#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" />
                AND trans_location IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.location#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" />  )
    </cfquery>

    <cfquery name="allLocCode" dbtype="query">
        SELECT DISTINCT trans_location, COUNT(*) AS locationCount FROM GetLocationInfo Where trans_location is not null GROUP BY trans_location ORDER BY trans_location
    </cfquery>

    <cfset columnSum = ArraySum(allLocCode['locationCount'])>
    <cfset checkListPercentage = arrayNew(1)>

<table border="1" id="Checklist_Stats">
  <thead>
    <th><strong>Location</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Percent of Total Checklists</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Location Total</strong></th> 
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <cfloop query="allLocCode">
        <cfset thisLocationName = trim(allLocCode.trans_location) />

    <cfquery name="allLocCodeForLocationQry" dbtype="query">
        SELECT trans_location,count(*) AS locCntr FROM GetLocationInfo WHERE trans_location='#thisLocationName#' GROUP BY trans_location ORDER BY trans_location
    </cfquery>

    <cfoutput query="allLocCodeForLocationQry">
        <cfset currentPercentage = (allLocCodeForLocationQry.locCntr / columnSum * 100)>
        <cfset arrayAppend(checkListPercentage, currentPercentage)>
        <cfset totalPercentage = arraySum(checkListPercentage)>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>#thisLocationName#</strong></td>
      <td>#numberFormat(currentPercentage, '9.99')#%</td>
      <td>#allLocCodeForLocationQry.locCntr#</td>
    </tr>
   </cfoutput>
   </cfloop>
   <tr>
   <cfoutput>
    <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
    <td>#numberFormat(totalPercentage, '9.99')#%</td>
    <td>#columnSum#</td>
    </cfoutput>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cfset result.error = CFCATCH.message >
        <cfset result.detail = CFCATCH.detail >
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>


    </cfcontent>

</cfif>
```

Comment: Not being sarcastic, but ... did you search before posting this question? :) The reason for asking is there are a *LOT* of posts on how to generate an Excel download (or faux-html-Excel download) through the use of cfheader and cfcontent, both on SO and the major search engines. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507973/how-can-i-download-to-excel/4547221#4547221.

Comment: i really did lol. But my screen that is appearing using these is not like the save as dialog box that they are requesting. And I haventfound an example of that yet :/

Comment: @Leigh I added an image of the box i keep getting which is not the correct type =/

Comment: (Edit) Well, unless you changed something - the code above is not doing *exactly* the same thing as the link posted is it? ;-) Start by asking yourself what is wrong with the dialog box? Obviously it is displaying the name of the current .cfm script.  If you look at the linked example, one thing that is different/missing is the `cfheader` .. which is how the browser gets the file name.

Comment: right I saw that and added it but the dialog box is still wrong. lol am i missing something? I feel like your dangling it over my head hahahaah

Comment: @Leigh i adjusted my code to show you. I really have searched all over trying to figure out how to present a Microsoft Windows Save As box instead of the little box below that is showing

Comment: What do you mean by "Windows Save as box"? Like I mentioned below, A browser download dialog is *not* the same as a desktop application dialog. Browser's have security restrictions that desktop applications do not.  An important of troubleshooting is to isolate the issue and create a stand alone repro case (when possible). Use the code in the link I posted to do that. Example: [small, stand alone, repro case](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/eecabd6f9d852e983db977e256901aa1).  Notice, it works and displays "fileName.xls"? In terms of dialogs, that is as good as it gets with an HTML download.

Comment: I understand that they want it to be like the first picture though where the user can drill down to where they can save it haveing the filename blank so they can enter the name they desire and set the save as type as xls =/ are you saying this is definitely not possible because its a browser?

Comment: **Please stop deleting all/most of your comments**. Once in a while is okay, but if everything is removed, so is a significant amount of context for the discussion as a whole, and the other comments no longer make any sense ;-)  Remember threads are preserved to help others too, not just you.

Comment: i didnt delete anything did i?

Comment: The dialog box you want is already in excel, and people can use it after they open the file.  What you say you want to do would likely result in the option to open the file to disappear.  For this, and other reasons, what you are contemplating is a bad idea.

Comment: Comments can be flagged and then deleted by moderators.  It wasn't me though.

Comment: The users are requiring me to do it this way =/ If its possible I will have to figure it out =/ I just am trying to find out if its even possible

Comment: @DanBracuk - Agreed. I cannot rule it out, but have noticed it has happened consistently on almost every one of David Brierton's threads. Usually moderators delete things for being too chatty or inappropriate/off topic. Since [the thread in question [only involved two (2) comments](http://tinypic.com/r/6qyvwh/9) - David's and mine, and the comment was certainly on topic, I am not sure why it would be deleted. David - Sorry if it was not you. It is just frustrating when whole *segments* of a thread, rather than the whole thread, disappear without reason.

Comment: Tell the users that it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following cfheader with a XLS-filename after cfcontent:

> <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="yourfilename.xls">

Comment: An HTML download dialog is not the same as a "Save As" dialog in a desktop application. Browser's have greater restrictions for security reasons. The "file name" is just a suggestion to the browser, which is free to modify or ignore it. However, seeing is believing. Test it out yourself and see what happens.